# Mathematica not computing Matrix problem, just returning multiplication expression

Tags: matrix, output-formatting

I'm doing some very simple matrix operations in Mathematica, but for some reason, the last operation I'm trying to evaluate is not returning the actual product, just shows the symbolic multiplication.

```
P = {
{1, 2},
{3, 4}} /10;

im = {{1},{1}}
in = {{1},{1}}

A = ArrayFlatten[ {
{KroneckerProduct[in\[Transpose], IdentityMatrix[2]]},
{KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[2], im\[Transpose]]}
} ]

p = Flatten[P] // MatrixForm

A.p
```

This last operation, $A\cdot p$ is returning the following:

[image]

Why is that so?

Comment: You simply have a typo: in should be im. Notice the color a variable is displayed and you will see which variables has no value and are possibly a typo.

Comment: There should really be some kind of standard tutorial for this that all new Mathematica programmers get to read or some kind of warning when doing calculations, but `MatrixForm` and all other `*Form` functions are simply display wrappers. Inside calculations they shouldn't be used, since Mathematica will just treat things as inert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
P={{1,2},{3,4}}/10;

im={{1},{1}}

A=ArrayFlatten[{{KroneckerProduct[im\[Transpose],IdentityMatrix[2]]},{KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[2],im\[Transpose]]}}]

p=Flatten[P]

A.p
```

1. a typo: `in` -> `im`
2. **Don't** use `MatrixForm` during calculation, unless you know it.

Comment: It's actually the MatrixForm. Which is weird.

Comment: It's not weird... MatrixForm is a typesetting command, like LatexForm. Don't use it in calculations.

Comment: Thanks! I didn’t know, thought it was just for notebook display.